# Is my game gravity frame independent?

Tags: android, libgdx

Here is my game gravity:

```
    if (position.y > 0 && isAlive) {
        velocity.add(0, GRAVITY);
    }
    velocity.scl(dt);
    if(isAlive) {
        position.add(MOVEMENT * dt, velocity.y);
        velocity.scl(1 / dt);
    }
```

Here, dt is supplied by Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(). The code looks fine and works fine on desktop, but on my phone, the jumps and gravity are slower and longer(even though it looks like it is running at 60fps). Am I missing something? The GRAVITY is a final variable I set.

Comment: Gravity also needs to multiplied by delta time. That will get you close enough for a non-competitive game. Otherwise you need to read up on fixed time steps with interpolation.

Comment: Isn't gravity already being multiplied by delta time in velocity.scl(dt)?

Comment: It needs to be multiplied by dt to get the velocity change. Then the velocity needs to be multiplied by dt to get the position change. Think about the units they would be in the metric system. Gravity is in meters per second squared. Delta time is in seconds. Multiply gravity by delta time to get meters per second change since the last frame.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Hmm... That looks right. I'll try tomorow the code and I'll post here how it worked

Comment: Ok, I changed GRAVITY to GRAVITY * dt, but now the character is not falling at all!

Comment: IT WORKED! All I had to do after I multiplied GRAVITY by dt was to increase it significantly and now it works on the phone as well! Thank you, fine sir!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the following:
GRAVITY needed to be multiplied by dt and increased significantly. Now it works like a charm both on desktop and mobile device!